# Android setBackgroundResource doesn't use image depend on dpi

Tags: android

I wan't to use the setBackgroundResource method to set an image to a button.

I have different folders with the same button in different dpi's but when I set the button from code it uses the drawable folder instead of the correct folder

```
resume.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.resumegrey);
```

[image: folders]

the resumegrey is copied in the right folders with diffrent dpi's

Comment: I bet that is an emulator issue. Try on a real device.

Comment: no on real devices to

Answer (score 0):

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
float density = metrics.density;
```

density is float and its value changed as per screen size...

so,if you have

```
240*320 density is 0.5
320*480 density is 1.0
480*800 density is 1.5
```

and set size using density like , img.setMaxHeight(density*100);

and also put multiple screen supports in manifest file.[Multiple Screen Support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: hmm don't think this helps me, see when u define different folders with hpdi, ldpi and so on it automatically takes the right buttons, but when i set the button with code it uses for every screen the same button